# ember lost reference to model on reload

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have routes like this

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('about');
  this.route('rooms');
  this.route('room', { path: '/room/:uid' });
```

when I access `/rooms` I can see the room list. Then I click in one room and I'm redirected to `/room/123` and everything works fine.
But if I reload the page on `/room/123` the model become `null`.

This is the route for room:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params){
    return this.store.findRecord('room', params.uid);
  }
});
```

Comment: You are missing return for model hook in room route.

Comment: do you pass model or id into link-to ? if model - than looks like @kumkanillam right

Comment: @kumkanillam you were right! that solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

You need to uses a getter to get the store.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params){
    return this.get('store').findRecord('room', params.uid);
  }
});
```

Comment: what is the difference? I know that store know is service, but it still injected into routes

Comment: actually the problem was the `return`

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget `return` statement in model hook of room route.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model(params){
    return this.store.findRecord('room', params.uid);
  }
});
```